# Can't get Django Channels websockets to connect. Using Django, Daphne and Nginx on Ubuntu 22 with Supervisor

Tags: django, nginx, websocket, django-channels, daphne

I have been working on getting this figured out for days and I feel like I am close to getting it but I have no idea what to try next.

This is how my code is setup:

- I use Celery to pull data from 2 apis and upload them to my database.
- I have a post_save method that sends serialized data to my consumers.py
- I have a javascript script that reads the websocket and plots it.

I have a webpage with 3 websockets and 2 of them work fine but one of them I can't get to work and I can't figure out how to troubleshoot it.

models.py showing the Gex model which isn't working and the Breadth model which is working.

```
import json
from django.db import models
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Notice(models.Model):
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    notice = models.TextField()

    def get_date_posted(self, obj):
        return obj.date_posted.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.date_posted} {self.notice}'


class Gex(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    expiration = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    ratio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    spot = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    zero_gamma = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    major_pos_vol = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    major_pos_oi = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    major_neg_vol = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    major_neg_oi = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    sum_gex_vol = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    sum_gex_oi = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    delta_risk_reversal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Last record: {self.timestamp} ticker: {self.ticker} exp: {self.expiration} ratio: {self.ratio}'

@receiver(post_save, sender=Gex, dispatch_uid="update_frontend_gex")
def update_frontend_gex(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    ts = instance.timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    message = {"timestamp": ts,
               "major_pos_vol": float(instance.major_pos_vol),
               "major_neg_vol": float(instance.major_neg_vol),
               "zero_gamma": float(instance.zero_gamma),
               "spot": float(instance.spot),
               "sum_gex_vol": float(instance.sum_gex_vol)}

    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        'zero_gex',
        {
            'type': 'message_to_frontend_gex',
            'message': json.dumps(message)
        }
    )
    return

class Breadth(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    fang = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    super_fang = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    nyse = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    nasdaq = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    nq100 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    sp500 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    rty = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    us = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Created {self.timestamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")} FANG:{self.fang} FANG+:{self.super_fang} NYSE:{self.nyse} SP500:{self.sp500} ' \
               f'NQ:{self.nasdaq} NQ100:{self.nq100} RTY:{self.rty} US:{self.us}'


@receiver(post_save, sender=Breadth, dispatch_uid="update_frontend_breadth")
def update_frontend_breadth(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    message = {"timestamp": instance.timestamp,
               "fang": float(instance.fang),
               "super_fang": float(instance.super_fang),
               "nyse": float(instance.nyse),
               "nasdaq": float(instance.nasdaq),
               "nq100": float(instance.nq100),
               "sp500": float(instance.sp500),
               "rty": float(instance.rty),
               "us": float(instance.us),
               }
    #
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        'breadth',
        {
            'type': 'message_to_frontend_breadth',
            'message': json.dumps(message)
        }
    )
    return
```

consumers.py showing the GexConsumer which isn't working and the BreadthConsumer which is working.

```
import json

from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer, WebsocketConsumer
from djangochannelsrestframework import permissions
from djangochannelsrestframework.generics import GenericAsyncAPIConsumer
from djangochannelsrestframework.observer import model_observer
from djangochannelsrestframework.mixins import ListModelMixin

from .models import Notice
from .serializers import NoticeSerializer


class ZeroGexConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self, **kwargs):
        self.accept()
        self.room_group_name = "gex"
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json["message"]
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name, {
                "type": 'chat.message',
                "message": message
            }
        )

    def message_to_frontend_gex(self, event):
        print('GexConsumer Event Triggered')
        message = json.loads(event['message'])
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))


class BreadthConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self, **kwargs):
        self.accept()
        self.room_group_name = "breadth"
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json["message"]
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name, {
                "type": 'message_to_frontend',
                "message": message
            }
        )

    def message_to_frontend_breadth(self, event):
        print('BreadthConsumer Event Triggered')
        message = json.loads(event['message'])
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

This shows the javascript code for both websockets (which are in different files) and imported into my html.

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws/gex/zero_gex/')

socket.onmessage = function(e){
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    var message = data['message']

var breadthSocket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host +  '/ws/gex/breadth/')

breadthSocket.onmessage = function (e) {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    var message = data['message']
```

This is my supervisor.conf

```
[fcgi-program:asgi]
# TCP socket used by Nginx backend upstream
socket=tcp://localhost:8000

user=root

# Directory where your site's project files are located
directory=/home/dmckim

# Each process needs to have a separate socket file, so we use process_num
# Make sure to update "mysite.asgi" to match your project name
command=/home/dmckim/venv/bin/daphne -u /run/daphne/daphne%(process_num)d.sock --fd 0 --access-log - --proxy-headers django_ml_platform.asgi:application

# Number of processes to startup, roughly the number of CPUs you have
numprocs=4

# Give each process a unique name so they can be told apart
process_name=asgi%(process_num)d

# Automatically start and recover processes
autostart=true
autorestart=true

# Choose where you want your log to go
stdout_logfile=/home/dmckim/asgi.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

This is what my asgi.log shows

```
2023-09-12 15:07:45,135 INFO     Starting server at fd:fileno=0, unix:/run/daphne/daphne1.sock
2023-09-12 15:07:45,164 INFO     HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2023-09-12 15:07:45,171 INFO     Configuring endpoint fd:fileno=0
2023-09-12 15:07:45,208 INFO     Starting server at fd:fileno=0, unix:/run/daphne/daphne2.sock
2023-09-12 15:07:45,215 INFO     HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2023-09-12 15:07:45,216 INFO     Configuring endpoint fd:fileno=0
2023-09-12 15:07:45,207 INFO     Starting server at fd:fileno=0, unix:/run/daphne/daphne0.sock
2023-09-12 15:07:45,224 INFO     HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2023-09-12 15:07:45,224 INFO     Configuring endpoint fd:fileno=0
2023-09-12 15:07:45,232 INFO     Listening on TCP address 127.0.0.1:8000
2023-09-12 15:07:45,239 INFO     Configuring endpoint unix:/run/daphne/daphne1.sock
2023-09-12 15:07:45,239 INFO     Starting server at fd:fileno=0, unix:/run/daphne/daphne3.sock
2023-09-12 15:07:45,247 INFO     HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2023-09-12 15:07:45,251 INFO     Configuring endpoint fd:fileno=0
2023-09-12 15:07:45,256 INFO     Listening on TCP address 127.0.0.1:8000
2023-09-12 15:07:45,258 INFO     Listening on TCP address 127.0.0.1:8000
2023-09-12 15:07:45,259 INFO     Configuring endpoint unix:/run/daphne/daphne2.sock
2023-09-12 15:07:45,263 INFO     Configuring endpoint unix:/run/daphne/daphne0.sock
2023-09-12 15:07:45,273 INFO     Listening on TCP address 127.0.0.1:8000
2023-09-12 15:07:45,273 INFO     Configuring endpoint unix:/run/daphne/daphne3.sock
72.191.131.252:0 - - [12/Sep/2023:15:08:29] "GET /gex/api/gex_timeseries/zero/ES/?format=json" 200 228033
72.191.131.252:0 - - [12/Sep/2023:15:08:29] "WSCONNECTING /ws/gex/breadth/" - -
72.191.131.252:0 - - [12/Sep/2023:15:08:29] "WSCONNECT /ws/gex/breadth/" - -
BreadthConsumer Event Triggered
BreadthConsumer Event Triggered
BreadthConsumer Event Triggered
```

And this is my nginx error.log

```
2023/09/12 19:08:28 [error] 62339#62339: *1 connect() failed (111: Unknown error) while connecting to upstream, client: 72.191.131.252, server: 138.68.232.138, request: "GET /gex/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:8000/gex/", host: "138.68.232.138", referrer: "http://138.68.232.138/gex/breadth_timeseries/"
```

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this since it worked fine on my local machine but I can't get this websocket to work on a production server. I haven't even set up https yet which I feel like is going to cause a whole new set of issues.